# Convert class component to functional component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm learning React hooks so in order to do that I'm trying to convert a class component to a functional component but I still get some errors.

Here is the original working component written as a class:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NavBar from './components/navbar';
import Counters from './components/counters';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    counters: [
      { id: 0, value: 5 },
      { id: 1, value: 1 },
      { id: 2, value: 2 },
    ],
  };

  handleDelete = (counterId) => {
    const counters = this.state.counters.filter((c) => c.id !== counterId);
    this.setState({ counters });
  };

  handleReset = () => {
    const counters = this.state.counters.map((c) => {
      c.value = 0;
      return c;
    });
    this.setState({ counters });
  };

  handleIncrement = (counter) => {
    const counters = [...this.state.counters];
    const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
    counters[index] = { ...counter };
    counters[index].value++;
    this.setState({ counters });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <NavBar
          totalCounters={this.state.counters.filter((c) => c.value > 0).length}
        />
        <main className='container'>
          <Counters
            counters={this.state.counters}
            onReset={this.handleReset}
            onDelete={this.handleDelete}
            onIncrement={this.handleIncrement}
          />
        </main>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And this is the converted version which uses hooks.

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import NavBar from './components/navbar';
    import Counters from './components/counters';
    
    const App = () => {
      const [counters, setCounters] = useState([
        { id: 0, value: 5 },
        { id: 1, value: 1 },
        { id: 2, value: 2 },
      ]);
    
      const handleDelete = (counterId) => {
        const counterss = counters.filter((c) => c.id !== counterId);
        setCounters({ counterss });
      };
    
      const handleReset = () => {
        const counterss = counters.map((c) => {
          c.value = 0;
          return c;
        });
        setCounters({ counterss });
      };
    
      const handleIncrement = (counter) => {
        const counterss = [...counters];
        const index = counterss.indexOf(counter);
        counterss[index] = { ...counter };
        counterss[index].value++;
        setCounters({ counterss });
      };
    
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <NavBar totalCounters={counters.filter((c) => c.value > 0).length} />
          <main className='container'>
            <Counters
              counters={counters}
              onReset={handleReset}
              onDelete={handleDelete}
              onIncrement={handleIncrement}
            />
          </main>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    };
    
    export default App;
```

Most of it works fine but it keeps throwing an error saying that filter is not a function. Here it is the message:

> TypeError: counters.filter is not a function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main culprit appears to be the way you are updating your state, which is like this:

```
setCounters({ counterss });
```

This will actually set your `counters` state to an object with the property `counterss`, so your state will contain the following:

```
{ counterss: [/* rest of the array */] }
```

The exact error being thrown is referring to the fact that you are attempting to call `.filter` on an object instead of an array. To fix this issue you should simply update your state like this:

```
setCounters(counterss);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
setCounters({ counterss })
```

should be

```
setCounters(counterss)
```

Answer (score 3):

It throws an error because you set the new state as an object `setCounters({ counterss });`. But you want an array: `setCounters(counterss);`. This way it won't throw an error the second time `setCounters` is called.